# Laravel and Xampp permission issues

Tags: linux, laravel, permissions, xampp

I'm pretty new to Linux (Mint) and I've installed xampp and cloned my Git repo.

The problem is that I don't have permissions to access the files, so I ran `chmod 755` but any new files have the same problem.

Error message:

> failed to open stream: Permission denied

I'm wondering if I installed xampp incorrectly or if using `sudo` when I run commands like `php artisan migrate` or `composer update` that my user loses access to those files?

What is going on here?

Comment: try to put `chmod 777`

Comment: @AlexanderVillalobos would that make any difference as 7 just adds excu permission ?

Comment: 777 get all permisions on this

Comment: 777 does work but i would need to do it for every future laravel project and i do not want to grant those kind of permissions when it goes live. is there no way to fix this once and for all?

Comment: stop in the system folder run cmd and put this command `sudo chmod 744 -R` and your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: chown the root directory:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/root
```

Step 2: Grant FTP for uploading and working with files (for using any FTP client):

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data ubuntu
```

Step 3: Set file permission to 644:

```
sudo find /path/to/root -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Step 4: Set directory permission to 755:

```
sudo find /path/to/root -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

Step 5: Give rights for web server to read and write storage and cache

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Reference : https://vijayasankarn.wordpress.com/2017/02/04/securely-setting-file-permissions-for-laravel-framework/

Comment: This is not technically the answer i needed but non the less great answer for when you go live with your project thank you! +1